# ASP.NET RAZOR The type or namespace name does not exist in the namespace (but it exists)

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor

Im trying to use an object called DBUser (which located in the namespace DevicesHub.DAL.DBClasses) in cshtml page.

In the same solutions I have the projects DevicesHub.DAL and DevicesHub.WebApplication.

Before running the web application it won't show any problem:
[I can't see where is the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ncS4r.png)

In the project DevicesHub.DAL I have a namespace called DevicesHub.DAL.DBClass.

This is the problem I have:
[View problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hp07d.png)

> - So in order to fix it I tryed adding reference from DevicesHub.DAL to the DevicesHub.WebApplication project.
> - In addition I tryed to adding the reference to the app.config file:

```
<pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
  <namespaces>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization"/>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
    <add namespace="DevicesHub.DAL.DBClasses" />

  </namespaces>
```

> - I tryed to remove the obj folder, the temp folder, clean the
>   project and the solution.
> - Also, I tryed to change all the projects' .net versions.
> - Nothing helped and I stack with this problem for hours.

Comment: Have you tried putting:

@using DevicesHub.DAL.DBClasses;

In the top of your view?

Comment: Yes, and still getting the same problem

Comment: What is the namespace in the DBUser file?

Comment: The namespace is DevicesHub.DAL.DBClasses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I have fixed It .
I found that I can add another project as a reference to the website.

So, I copied the project and created the project that didn't work again.

I have no idea why but that fixed it.